# FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Invalid database id [object Object]

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I recently cloned a website I made and set up a new Firebase project for it. I basically ran create-react-app and firebase init then copied in all of the components. The site seems to run fine, and even Firebase Auth works for logging users in and out, but when it tries to read or write to the Firestore database, I get the following error:

```
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.19.1): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Invalid database id [object Object]
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

I've checked all of the security rules on the database, and everything seems to match the original project (obviously besides the project-specific settings like the apiKey, authDomain, etc). Any ideas on what's causing the error?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Also based on this [github link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7046#issuecomment-1442440369), you need to replace `getFirestore` with `initializeFirestore` within your code.

Comment: Changing getFirestore to initializeFirestore was the solution. Thanks very much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously posted in the comments, based on the [github link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7046#issuecomment-1442440369) that I provided, you need to replace `getFirestore` to `initializeFirestore` within your code.